# Can not edit primary key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making an application in c# using MVC and ASP.NET. I have a `Year` entity that is a table of years and a primary ID, called `YearID`. When I go to edit the YearID though, it will not change. Can you not edit primary keys? Is there any way to fix this? YearID has to be the primary key.

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="YearID")] Year year)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(year).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    return View(year);
}
```

Year Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Utility.Models
{
    public class Year
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int YearID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit html:
    @model Utility.Models.Year

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Year</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YearID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"             })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Let me know if any more code is needed.

Comment: Does this editing work with anything other?

Comment: Yeah, it has worked with several other programs of mine, the only difference with this one is that I am trying to edit the primary key.

Comment: Is there an error being thrown when you try to edit the primary key? If you try to change its value to something that is already a primary key value in the database, it will fail.

Comment: AFAIK you can't really change PK in ASp MVC. Most important question is: why would you want to do that? I think you misunderstand the PK / FK concept. Note that changing the PK would require you to also change all FK instances.

Comment: Entity Framework links entities to the context by their primary key.

You cannot edit the primary key once the record has been created with that primary key, as that makes it a different record entirely.

Instead you have to create a new record with the new primary key and delete the old one.

Or you could detach your Model from EF, and then create a new record or select an existing one based on the value of YearID from the form.

Comment: What is the exception that you're getting when you try to change the value of the primary key?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to say, it does not give me an error, it carries on as normal as if it changed, but the value is the same.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to change the generated ID of your PK?

Comment: I just wanted the give the user the option to change it but it is not a big important feature. Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: The user should never see or even be aware of an ID column.